# Reporte en ReportViewer C#, windows form, ocultar columnas según decida el usuario

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer, rdlc, reporte

Estoy haciendo un reporte[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] sencillo usando **ReportViewer**, donde muestro todos los campos de una tabla, funciona bien, pero lo que necesito es que se **genere el reporte solamente con las columnas que el usuario decida**, la verdad no se como se puede hacer, agradezco mucho que me puedan ayudar.

```
        '''ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
        rds.Name = "DataSet1";
        rds.Value = N_ProductList.MostarRegistros();

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
       // reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas puedes conseguirlo desde las propiedades de tablix de cada columna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberás pasarle un parámetro booleano a la expresion a partir de unos checkBox por ejemplo que devulevan true o false si están seleccionados o no y vincularlo a la columna que desees al true o false de visible

```
 =Parameters!Ocultar.Value = True
```

Comment: muchas gracias... eso mismo es lo que necesito, los checkbox los pongo en el formulario que tiene el reportViewer, pero ¿cómo la expresión del Hidden de la columna la puedo vincular con un checkbox específico? ¿sabes de algún link dónde se explique esto con más detalles ? ... muchas gracias
Te intenté dar +1 pero no me deja porque recién me acabo de registrar

Comment: Ya lo resolví gracias !!!